# Share Firebase Authentication between Chrome and Chrome Plugin

Tags: firebase, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a web application where my users can log in through either user/ pass or Google, using Firestore to manage users/ auth.

I also have a Chrome extension that needs to leverage the same authentication session if possible - i.e stays logged in, token can easily be revoked if needed, and no need to type username/ password into the Chrome extension.

It is easy to do this by grabbing the user logged into *Chrome* (Not my app explicitly, but in most cases this is the same thing). This works fine using OAuth2.

Reading the docs, username/ password authentication seems to suggest you use Firebase Admin in a server environment to generate and return a token. This then creates more complexity around managing tokens, logouts, and revocation from what I can see.

I am wondering if it is possible to simply share the logged in state between Chrome and the Chrome extension via pushing the Firebase session/auth data in IndexedDb from the browser to the Chrome Extension in a content script? Would this effectively give the plugin the same 'session' as the main browser? Is there any risk in doing this?

Thanks